# Is there any known performance difference between Item.Axes.GetDescendants() and recursive Item.GetChildren()?

Tags: performance, api

I was wondering if there is any **known difference** (mostly performance related) between those two methods of retrieving all children of a given Item.

The first one will give me all levels of children in one shot.

On the second approach, I have to build some code to recursively get the same result, since `Item.GetChildren()` only returns the first level.

I don't know why but I had a feeling that the `Item.Axes.GetDescendants()` was **always slower**, but using DotPeek to see what is going on under the hoods now I'm no longer sure.

## Item.Axes.GetDescendants()

It uses the `item.Children` property.

Which ends up calling `ItemManager.GetChildren(this._ownerItem, (ChildListOptions.IgnoreSecurity & options) != ChildListOptions.None ? SecurityCheck.Disable : SecurityCheck.Enable).InnerChildren`

## Recursive Item.GetChildren()

Which is also `ItemManager.GetChildren(this, (options & ChildListOptions.IgnoreSecurity) != ChildListOptions.None ? SecurityCheck.Disable : SecurityCheck.Enable, options)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some benchmarks using those two possibilities.

## Scenario

Fetch 2040 items organized in the following way:

```
Root Item
    - Bulk Items 1
        - Bulk Items 1.1        
        (100 items)     
    (100 items)
    - Bulk Items 2.1
        - Bulk Items 2.1        
        (100 items) 
    [...]
    (100 items)
    - Bulk Items 10
        - Bulk Items 10.1       
        (100 items)     
    (100 items)
```

## Using GetDescendants()

```
IEnumerable<Item> kids = Database.GetItem(rootItemId).Axes.GetDescendants().ToList();
```

## Using GetChildren() recursively

```
IEnumerable<Item> kids = FetchAllChildrenItems(Database.GetItem(rootItemId)).ToList();

private IEnumerable<Item> FetchAllChildrenItems(Item p_Item, bool p_ReturnRootItem = false)
{
    if (p_ReturnRootItem) {
        yield return p_Item;
    }

    foreach (Item child in p_Item.GetChildren(ChildListOptions.SkipSorting))
    {
        foreach (Item subChild in FetchAllChildrenItems(child, true)) {
            yield return subChild;
        }
    }
}
```

## Results (in milliseconds)

After running both scenarios **without any element cached at all** (after restarting the IIS Pool on every run), those are the results I collected:

```
1. GetDescendants():
    4529.0435
    2880.6591
    3169.9953
    2709.0039
    Average: 3322.1754
 2. Children - Recursive:
    2305.6319
    2470.5706
    2372.3421
    2581.8652
    Average: 2432.6024
```

And those are the results when the tests were performed after all those elementes are cached properly:

```
 1. GetDescendants():
    34.0887
    27.0741
    18.0443
    21.054
    24.0315
    29.0764
    Average: 25.5615
 2. Children - Recursive:
    15.0413
    19.0475
    20.0525
    17.0444
    16.0744
    24.0643
    Average: 18.5540
```

So it looks like that even if the results are pretty close, **using the method Item.GetChildren() recursively** can be a little bit faster than the Item.Axes.GetDescendants().

Answer (score 5):

Much faster way is to get descendants from index.

Query would be get all items that Path starts (contains) the same as current item + ID of item is different to current one.

Something like this:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable()
   .Where(item => item["_path"].Contains(contentRootId))
   .Where(item => !item.ID.Equals(contentRootId));
```

Solr can perform this in just few miliseconds.

Comment: If Solr document is enough. But how fast is it when you have to get the original item after? Maybe another series of tests? :)